# Can I use a jsp tag to hide an input field on load

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need to hide a field on page load based on the value of a request attribute.  I don't want a 'hidden' field because I want to show it again.  I don't want to do this with javascript.  How is this done with jsp tags?

Comment: Why do you not want to use javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set a condition where display is block if the condition is true. Else if the condition is false set the display to none.

```
<c:set var="inputDisplay" value="1" /> <!-- This same as your request attribute -->
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${inputDisplay == 1}">
        <input type="text" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" />
    </c:otherwise>      
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 16):

Use the conditional operator in EL.

```
<div class="${hide ? 'hide' : 'show'}">
```

where `${hide}` is the request attribute evaluating to a `boolean`. If it evaluates `true`, then the class name `"hide"` will be printed, else the class name `"show"` will be printed.

Of course define those classes in your stylesheet as well.

```
.hide { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

No need for JSTL tags here.

---

Or if you don't want to use CSS class definitions for some unobvious reason, then do

```
<div style="display:${hide ? 'none' : 'block'}">
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code will only show include the code between the tags if `requestAttribute` evaluates to `true` to have the opposite effect use `${not requestAttribute}` instead.

```
<c:if test="${requestAttribute}">
    //Code here
</c:if>
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the field on load, I want to hide it, so that I can show it again.  The only way I've found to do this is with javascript.

Comment: When would you "show it again"?...when the user clicks a link?, when the user types something in? something else?